# What does "--" mean in terminal commands?

Tags: command-line

I have seen many tutorials that use a `--` after commands. Something like this:

```
command --
```

What does this `--` mean?

Comment: What video tutorials?

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11376/6949.

Comment: Actually, I am surprised that this question was not already a dupe on AU.  Do identical questions on other StackExchange communities not count as dupes (viz the link given by @edwinksl) ?  What's the take on that ? Maybe I should ask that on META....

Comment: @Cbhihe I am not aware of a mechanism that allows us to point to duplicate targets of other SE sites. Anyway, it doesn't happen too often, so there is probably no need for one.

Comment: @Cbhihe [no they don't, unfortunately.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4708/2031010).

Comment: Surely you could migrate it and then dupe?

Comment: @anonymous2 why in the world would we do that? The question is on topic here, so it can stay. Moving it would remove information from AU and add nothing new to U&L, so I don't see why it would be a good thing.

Comment: Fair and fine, @terdon.  I wasn't referring to this question *particularly*, however.  I guess I'll wait for the meta post to share thoughts, however.  :)

Comment: @anonymous: see my post on Meta: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15720/dupes-accross-stackexchange-sites-how-to-treat-them

Answer (score 48):

The `--` is used to indicate the end of command line options. This enables you to use arguments starting with `--`. For example, if you create a file called `--foo`:

```
$ > '--foo'
$ ls
--foo
```

And then try to delete it, `rm` will think you're giving it an argument:

```
$ rm --foo 
rm: unrecognized option '--foo'
Try 'rm ./--foo' to remove the file '--foo'.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

One way around this is to use `--`:

```
$ rm -- --foo
```

This is common practice and [recommended by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02), so it's supported by many programs.

Comment: It is not implemented by Bash at all. It _is_ a feature of the `rm` program and of many POSIX-compliant utilities. See [Guideline 10](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02). To actually check that it isn't Bash doing the work (and that wouldn't make sense), just create a small script with just `printf '> %s <\n' "$@"` and launch it with `--`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf d'oh! I did check by writing a little perl script that prints its options and it doesn't see any if you pass it a `--`, but, of course, that's simply because the relevant Perl module (`getopts`) also supports it. You're quite right, I just quickly searched `man bash`, saw the section I had quoted but failed to notice that it was in the "command line options" section. Thanks for the correction, answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

Most commands will use a -- to tell the command that further parameters should be treated differently. One example is the rm -- --filename noted above. Another example, a script like 'startx' will interpret itself everything before -- , and pass everything after it to the X server.