# 'Overwrote' files, space still occupied, are they lost?

Tags: command-line, bash, files

So dumb impatient me used the following script on my 19.04 server in an attempt to move a bunch of video files into folders with prefixes :

```
dirs=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)
shopt -s nocasematch

for file in *
do
    for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
    do

     if [ -d "$file" ]; then
      echo 'this is a dir, skipping'
      break
     else
      if [[ $file =~ ^[$dir] ]]; then
       echo "----> $file moves into -> $dir <----"
       mv "$file" "$dir"
       break
      fi
     fi
  done
done
```

No clue where it went wrong, but instead of moving the files to folders it went to a singular output.. so :

```
----> a1.ts moves into -> A <----
----> a2.ts moves into -> A <----
----> a3.ts moves into -> A <----
----> a4.ts moves into -> A <----
----> a5.ts moves into -> A <----
----> c1.ts moves into -> C <----
----> c2.ts moves into -> C <----
----> c3.ts moves into -> C <----
----> c4.ts moves into -> C <----
----> c5.ts moves into -> C <----
```

I luckily stopped the process (CTRL+C) as soon as I noticed it wasn't going as intended and didn't go through the whole folder.

So now I've got those files `A` and `C`, which are less than a Gb, and by the looks of it are a SINGLE video.

There are 50Gb unaccounted for in the total disk use of the folder itself, but the overall disk space of the computer has remained the same.
Making me think the files aren't deleted ?

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

***Edit : the files are actually gone, only the last file to be written remains, all it took was some time for the disk use info to update.. moral of the story, run your scripts on mock files before !***

Comment: And did the directories named `A`, `B` and so on existed before running the script? If not you just renamed the files. All files which names started with `a` or `A` has been renamed to `A`, so only the last renamed file survived, the others are overwritten. To call a variable `dir` does not create a directory!

Comment: thats the way it interpreted it as well. "last renamed file survived" ha. directories didn't exist, i should have added a 'touch' for each before hand. thanks for clarifying

Comment: +1 for ".. moral of the story, run your scripts on mock files before !"

Comment: A tip to avoid problems like this: Use `mv "$file" "$dir/"`, with a trailing `/`; then if `$dir` doesn't exist, `mv` will error instead of rename `$file` to `$dir`. Also consider `mv -i` and `mv -n`. And always do a `mkdir -p` before moving, for good measure.

Comment: @sudodus Even better moral, "Always backup your data!".

Comment: but if my backups need backups.. what are we doing here, financing tech's company's wealth one drive at the time !

Comment: Could it be that they are opened by some process?

Comment: @CZed Adding `touch` means nothing in this case. It would result in the same thing - creating a file called A (touch would create the first file which happens to be empty) and overwriting that file with data each time. In which case you can safely delete the touch command and it would do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @CZed That's how backups work. Real backups are backups of backups - kind of like git but for the entire disk. Normally you'd have several periods of backups (days, weeks etc). To save disk space backups are often made of differences to previous backups instead of the entire disk. The algorithm can get fairly complicated. That is why backups is done via dedicated software instead of manually dragging folders to another disk - on MacOS you'd just activate Time Machine

Comment: Pro tip for next time, when moving files into a directory, end the destination path with a slash. This will cause it to fail if the directory doesn't exist and has saved me many a time.

Answer (score 14):

I think this is the problem: You should have created directories A, B, C ... Z. If you did, the `mv` command should have moved the files to those directories.

But if not, the `mv` command moves the files to files with those names, A, B, C ... and I think this is what you did.

To make the shellscript safer, you should make it create the directories (if they are not already there) before you start the moving.

```
dirs=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z)

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"
do
 mkdir -p $dir
done
```

If you want things to get even safer, you can also use `mv` with the `-i` option

```
   -i, --interactive
          prompt before overwrite
```

Comment: would adding `touch` be a good subsitute to `mkdir` as to avoid conflicts in case of running the script multiple times ?

Comment: `touch` creates a file if the name does not exist. So it will not do what you want in this case. `mkdir -p` can handle using the script several times.

Comment: Another simple way you can make `mv` safer is to get into the habit of adding a trailing slash to the target name when the target is a directory i.e. `mv "$file" "$dir/"`

Answer (score 7):

[@Sudodus already explained](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174093/85695) what went wrong, but here's a simpler version of your script for next time:

```
for letter in {a..z}; do 
    dir=${letter^}
    mkdir -p -- "$dir" 
    mv -- "$letter"* "${letter^^}"* "$dir"/
done
```

#### Explanation

- `for letter in {a..z}; do`: `{a..z}` expands to all lower case letters between `a` and `z`:

  ```
  $ echo {a..z}
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  ```

  So this will iterate over all lower case letters, saving each as `$letter`.
- `dir=${letter^}` : the syntax `${var^^}` returns the contents of the variable `$var` with the first character in upper case (since this only has *one* character, that's all we need). So, if `$letter` is `a`, then `${letter^^}` is `A`, and therefore `$dir` will be the upper case version of the current `$letter`.
- `mkdir -p -- "$dir"` : create the directory. If it already exists, do nothing (`-p`). The `--` [signifies the end of the options](https://askubuntu.com/q/794013/85695), and is useful to protect against names starting with `-`.
- `mv -- "$letter"* "${letter^}"* "$dir"` : move every file (or directory) to the relevant target.

The problem with this, is that it will also move any directories you may have. It won't move the target directories, because either they don't exist yet, or you will try to move them into themselves, but any existing dirs that aren't the target dir will be moved.

If that's a problem, you will have to do something like this:

```
for file in *; do 
    if [[ ! -d "$file" ]]; then 
        letter="${file:0:1}"
        dir="${letter^}"
        mkdir -p -- "$dir"
        mv -- "$file" "$dir"/
    fi
done
```

Comment: What's the difference between `${letter^}` and `${letter^^}`, and if they're identical, why use `${letter^^}` in place of `$dir`?

Comment: @NicHartley `${var^}` capitalizes the first letter only, while `${var^^}` capitalizes all letters. It doesn't make any difference here since `$letter` only has one letter.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, except you might want to add an extra layer of carefulness by adding a directory slash to `$dir` in the `mv`command.  (In its present form it will fail if a file preexists with a single-letter uppercase name)

Comment: @StigHemmer whoops, yes indeed. Very good point, thanks. Answer edited.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking every file against a dictionary array which creates alot of iteration you can match files against patterns.

**Very basic sort:**

```
#!/bin/bash

videos=./videos
sorted=./sorted

# sort types link,move.
sort_type=link

find "$videos" -maxdepth 1 -type f \
   \( -name '*.avi' -o -name '*.mkv' -o -name '*.mp4' \) -print0 |

while IFS= read -r -d ''; do

    b=$(basename "$REPLY")
    c=${b::1}

    case $c in
        [a-zA-Z]) label=${c^} ;; [0-9]) label="0-9" ;; *) label="_" ;;
    esac

    [[ ! -d "$sorted/$label" ]] && mkdir -p "$sorted/$label"

    if [[ -L $sorted/$label/$b ]] || [[ -e $sorted/$label/$b ]]; then
        echo "File/link: '$b' exists, skipping."
        continue
    fi

    case $sort_type in
        link)
            ln -rfst "$sorted/$label" -- "$REPLY"
            ;;
        move)
               mv -t "$sorted/$label" -- "$REPLY"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Maybe i did it wrong but that definetly didn't work, lost ten files lol.
I'm having troouble understaging the REPLY part? what's the intent
All that's left (inside folders A B C D ....) are the aliases files themselves pointing to .. tha alias

Comment: REPLY set to the line of input read by the read builtin command when no arguments are supplied.

Comment: ok and then at the end you do ***ln -rfst "$sorted/$label" -- "$REPLY"***
why do the alias if we just moved them with mv ?

Comment: As default it creates links from "videos" directory into your sorted directory, if you want to mv them you need to uncomment "Move videos" and comment "Link videos" (i think symlinks are less scary)

Comment: ...just not both at the same time.

Comment: ah so when you uncomment MV but don't comment link.. so links overwite the actual file ?

Comment: added check for existens of link/file in sort directory.

Answer (score 2):

Safeguard in your .bashrc:

```
alias mv="mv -n --backup=numbered"
```

Comment: @Zanna, Thanks for that! Added quotes.

Comment: Few questions just to be sure (being a newbie), adding in the **.zshrc** file is valid too (if using ZSH)?

in **man mv** it says `-n      Do not overwrite an existing file.  (The -n option overrides any previous -f or -i options.)` so does it matter that the **-n** tag will be before following tags?

The **--backup=numbered** will create a double of each right, isn't that a bit overkill (and space energy/consuming) when dealing with uber-large video files (talking terabytes). Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

For the record, some ways to stop `mv` from overwriting existing files:

- If you want to move to a directory, append a slash to the target, i.e. use `mv "$file" "$dir"/` instead of `mv "$file" "$dir"`. If `$dir` doesn't exist or isn't a directory, `mv` will complain:

  ```
  $ touch a
  $ mv a z/
  mv: cannot move 'a' to 'z/': Not a directory
  $ touch z
  $ mv a z/
  mv: failed to access 'z/': Not a directory
  ```

  This seems to make the system call `rename("a", "z/")`, so it should be safe from time-of-check-to-time-of-use vulnerabilities, in case someone is handling the same set of files at the same time.
- Alternatively, use `mv -t "$dir" "$file"`. Again, it'll complain if `$dir` isn't a directory.
- Use the `-n` option to prevent overwriting existing files:

  ```
  -n, --no-clobber
      do not overwrite an existing file
  ```

  It won't stop it from renaming the first file, but it won't then trash it with the others.

  This seems to call a plain `rename()`, so it might be not be safe with simultaneous handling. (There's [`renameat2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) that would support a flag to prevent overwriting.)

Answer (score 1):

While apparently not the case for you, it is possible that you could do this and not lose the files.  This would require one of two things to be true:

- One or more 'hard links' to the same files exist elsewhere on the filesystem
- One or more processes has a file open

Unix filesystems allow more than one *directory entry* to refer to the exact same *file content*.  This is called a '[hard link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)'.  You can create hard links with the `ln` command, *without* the common `-s` (soft/symbolic) option.  As long as at least one hard link exists to the file content, it will not be reused by the filesystem.

(Side note, permissions typically apply to the file content, not to the directory entry.  This is why an ordinary user can sometimes delete a file owned by `root`, but not write to it.  The delete operation modifies the folder, not the file itself.)

The filesystem will also not reuse file content as long as at least one process has the file open.  Even if no directory entry exists, the filesystem will not consider the space to be free until no processes have it open.  The file [can be recovered](https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process) from the virtual filesystem `/proc/<pid>/fd` by `root` as long as the file remains open.  (Thanks @fluffysheap.)

Comment: If there does happen to be a process with the file open, then you can recover it by looking it up in /proc/<pid>/fd.  See https://superuser.com/questions/283102/how-to-recover-deleted-file-if-it-is-still-opened-by-some-process