# Need to move files found using grep into a folder

Tags: grep, xargs

As part of a University course, I'm trying to reclusively search for a string in a list of 500 files, and then copy those items found into a new folder.

I can find the files without a problem using

```
grep -rnw '/home/steve/Desktop.CEDFOR.arnold-j/sent/' -e 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com'
```

However, when I try to pipe the results to a folder called Suspicious it errors.

The full code that I am using (based on a similar issue reported a couple of years back) is

```
grep -rnw '/home/steve/Desktop.CEDFOR.arnold-j/sent/' -e 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com' | xargs -0 cp -t /home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/Suspicious/
```

However, the error states that no such folder or file exists.  I can confirm that there the folder /home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/Suspicious/ is definitely there.

To clarify...  I want to copy the files to the folder "Suspicious", for review at a later point in time.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Welcome, your pipe is broken, you tagged the question `xargs`, but it's missing in your command `| -0...`. Shouldn't be `| xargs -0...`?

Comment: If you want grep to output just the *names of files* that contain matches, you need the `-l` (or long-form `--files-with-matches`) option

Comment: Apologies...  the xargs is definitely there.  I just messed up the copy/paste.

Comment: ...and if you intead using null-terminated output you should add `-Z` to `grep -lZR 'pattern' | xargs -0 cp -t target/ --`.

Comment: @bac0n...  I'm be honest mate, I'm unsure what you mean.  I have edited the question for clarification as to what exactly what I need to do.

Comment: Is your distro release really 14.04 like you tagged? `lsb_release -rd` please.

Comment: in the title you say "*move*", but in the text, you say "*copy*" and use "*cp*". Could you please clarify?

Comment: I meant copy, not move.  I'll update the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `grep` should be different, **it needs:**

- `-l, --files-with-matches`, only print files names, not matching lines
- `-Z, --null`, As your `xargs` reads zero-delimited output due to `-0`, which is a good idea, you also need to **provide** zero-delimited output with adding `-Z` to your `grep` command.
- `-F, --fixed-strings`, as you have a fixed string instead of a pattern, you should use `-F`. If not, your "pattern" would also match e.g. `vladimirXgorny@enron+com`, as `.` means *any character* in regex. Also `-F` will be a lot faster!

**It does not need:**

- `-n` prints line numbers of matches, but what should `xargs` do with it?

**It should be changed:**

- Although it works, your command should be changed to mach the format of the Synopsis, so you can be sure that it will work with different versions of `grep`, too. (compare `man grep`).

  > `grep [OPTION...] -e PATTERNS ... [FILE...]`

  Meaning your file (or in your case the path) should be placed after `-e ...`.

So, your full command would read:

```bsh
grep -rlZFw -e 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com' '/home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/sent/'
```

or you could leave out `-e` to match the first SYNOPSIS form:

```bsh
grep -rlZFw 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com' '/home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/sent/'
```

---

Your `xargs` looks fine to me, but you should consider adding `-r, --no-run-if-empty` to avoid errors when `grep` does not find any matching file.

And for your `cp` command, it's good habit to append `--` to tell `cp` that [no options are following](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794013/what-does-mean-in-terminal-commands). Otherwise, filenames beginning with `-` could cause trouble.

```bsh
xargs -0r cp -t /home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/Suspicious/ --
```

---

In total:

```bsh
grep -rlZFw 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com' '/home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/sent/' \
| xargs -0r cp -t /home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/Suspicious/ --
```

Comment: Hey pLumo... I have entered the post identically to what you suggested (grep -rlZFw 'vladimir.gorny@enron.com' '/home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/sent/' \ | xargs -0r cp -t  /home/steve/Desktop/CEDFOR/arnold-j/Suspicious/ --)... I did amend your reply slightly as the filepath had . instead of / which I assumed was a typo.  Anyways, the command failed...  grep:  invalid option -- 't'

Comment: Yes, the typo is from your question ;-) Regarding the error, please make sure to put it in 2 lines like I have written it **or** remove the backslash which is there to escape the newline.

Comment: Haha....  so it is.  Hadn't even noticed that lol.  That has worked like a charm.  Thank you very much!