# Compress folder of multiple pdfs in linux

Tags: pdf

I want to reduce unnecessary data on my hard disk, so I would like to shrink some pdfs.

It would be hard for me to use the command line interface for all those pdfs, right?

Is there a good solution for reducing e.g. all pdfs in one folder?

thank you.

Comment: PDFs are not very compressible, this is unlikely to be the best option for you.

Comment: Is there a reason why `gzip -9 *.pdf` wouldn't work for you?  (But yes, they aren't very compressible so you won't get much gains in disk space...)

Answer (score 3):

You can use ghostscript for that.

```
apt-get install ghostscript
```

Then, use ghostscript to reduce file space.

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
    -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -sOutputFile=compressed_file.pdf original_file.pdf
```

To do this for all PDF files in a folder, do:

```
for file in *pdf; do
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
    -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
        -sOutputFile="compressed_${file}" -- "$file"
done
```

Or, do also recurse into subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar 
for file in **/*pdf; do 
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
    -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET \
        -dBATCH -sOutputFile="${file//.pdf/_compressed.pdf}" -- "$file"
done
```

And, finally, to delete files after compressing (but don't run this before making sure the command works for you):

```
shopt -s globstar 
for file in **/*pdf; do 
    gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
        -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
            -sOutputFile="${file//.pdf/_compressed.pdf}" -- "$file" &&
    rm -- "$file"
done
```

The `--` is there to make sure this works even on file names beginning with `-`, see https://askubuntu.com/a/794014/85695.

Comment: Is it just me or does this only do one file?

Comment: @David yeah I also wonder right now  if its only one file!

Comment: ahh ok yeah, my mind thought in for looping it

Comment: Depending on the source PDF file, this may or may not reduce the size. It might in fact increase the size as well. It may result in a decrease in quality of the PDF size. Caveats worth mentioning in your answer. If only size matters, `-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen` will make smaller files.

Comment: my first try: 13 MB -> 18 MB hahah

Comment: i think it works . but it is really hard to use .. but I will check it deeper :D